# What kind of longhorn beetle is this?

Tags: species-identification

I live in Europe and found this interesting longhorn beetle I think and I was curious what species it is or what's it's name!
Thanks to anyone who identifies it!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rosalia alpina (common name: Rosalia longicorn)

See here: [Rosalia longicorn](https://de.dreamstime.com/stockfoto-k%C3%A4fer-rosalia-alpina-image70322077)

The link I added shows a picture of an identical Alpine Longhorn Beetle. This longhorn beetle occurs mainly in the European Alps and the neighboring countries (e.g. Germany, Hungary, and France). Minimum height is around 700m above sea level. The adults are active from June to September. The color varies between blue and grey, the head is characterized by one spine on each side of the head. The number of black dots on the elytra varies.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. For species ID answers we expect users to post an identifying picture and additional evidence that it is indeed the beetle in question, for example by mentioning geographical distribution and check whether that matches OP's location.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The link I added shows a picture of an identical Alpine Longhorn Beetle. This longhorn beetle occurs mainly in the European Alps and the neighboring countries (e.g. Germany, Hungary, and France). Minimum height is around 700m above sea level. The adults are active from June to September. The color varies between blue and grey, the head is characterized by one spine on each side of the head. The number of black dots on the elytra varies.

Comment: Also see https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Rosalia alpina for further pictures

Comment: You can edit the question to add this information to your answer. I think the downvotes are harsh when you appear to have the correct ID but those leaving them may reverse them following an edit.